# How to remove full screen mode in android app

Tags: java, android, android-fullscreen

I am new in android app development I didn't declare anything for full screen mode still it asks in bottom of my application during runtime for full screen mode only for device with small screen like redmi 6A [Here is output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33jYh.jpg)

Its just a demo app to ask for permission like call , contacts etc it works fine without crashing just i want to remove that option for full screen from bottom of the screen

would really be great full if anyone can guide
Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**
permission_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.android.dialer.PermissionActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">






</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your layout file

Comment: I have updated it